# Database and in-app purchases

Tags: ios, database, swift

I've looked for similar questions or a good answer, but I couldn't find anything. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate. I need help pointing me in the right direction.

I'm making an app that allows the user to create stories and upload them to a database where other users can download that story. I also plan on releasing in-app purchases with pre-made stories. I am not sure how to integrate in-app purchases or databases in code. This app will be on iOS, so I believe I have to use Swift. If anyone can help me with this, and just tell me things I need to learn, that would be incredible.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. Please read the [help]

Comment: Also bear in mind recommending off site resources is also off topic and your question needs to be about programming as this is a programming Q&A site not any computery based issues

Comment: Okay, I'll keep doing research and just try to find an answer. Thank you Liam.